# SQL test for prospective employees

Tags: sql, testing

I hope it's okay to ask this question here, but I'm wondering if anyone out there in the data analyst/IT community has developed a test for applicants to verify their sql skills at an intermediate to advanced level?

thank you!

-C

Comment: is there a stack exchange site that would be appropriate for this type of question? thx for the downvote, btw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an idea. For my last job, one SQL problem the posed was to solve the eight queens problem with pure SQL. Amongst many other problems.